# LWJGL 3 and JFrame

Tags: java, swing, awt, lwjgl, glfw

I want to create a model creator with LWJGL but It would be too complicated to create GUIs with OpenGL so I would like to use JFrame with it. The only answers that I found to that is using a previous version of LWJGL and putting it in a canvas using the Display class but I don't have this class.

Is there anyway to use Swing or AWT with LWJGL ? Or is there a library that could help me with that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Put a LWJGL java app in a jpanel or canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29048482/put-a-lwjgl-java-app-in-a-jpanel-or-canvas)

Comment: Si I have to use LWJGL 2 or use a different system to create my GUIs easily ?

Comment: It seems so. LWJGL3 is still fairly new, so I don't know of any decent GUI library. And because it doesn't do well with Swing, GUIs have to be created entirely with OpenGL instead of using the OS's GUI system.

Comment: (3 months later) What'd you end up doing?

Comment: I decided to get back to lwjgl 2